# Getopt joining parameters

Tags: c++, c, parameters, parameter-passing, getopt

Is there way using getopt function to parse:

```
./prog -L -U
```

as same as:

```
./prog -LU
```

This is my try (not working):

```
while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "LU")) != -1) {
    switch (c) {
    case 'L':
        // L catch
        break;
    case 'U':
        // U catch
        break;
    default:
        return;
    }
}
```

In this simple example are only 2 parameters but in my project are required all combinations of 6 parameters. For example: `-L` or `-LURGHX` or `-LU -RG -H` etc.
Can `getopt()` handle this? Or I must write complex parser to do that?

Comment: `getopt` should see your two examples in exactly the same way...  See the 2nd and 3rd example in the documentation here: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html#Example-of-Getopt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save for a missing brace, your code works fine for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int c;
    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "LU")) != -1) {
        switch (c) {
        case 'L':
            // L catch
            printf("L\n");
            break;
        case 'U':
            // U catch
            printf("U\n");
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

> ```
> $ ./a.out -LU
> L
> U
> $ ./a.out -L
> L
> $
> ```

Answer (score 2):

`getopt` [does seem capable of handling it](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Example-of-Getopt.html#Example-of-Getopt), [and it does](http://liveworkspace.org/code/2l00yg%2432)

> Here are some examples showing what this program prints with different combinations of arguments:

```
% testopt
aflag = 0, bflag = 0, cvalue = (null)

% testopt -a -b
aflag = 1, bflag = 1, cvalue = (null)

% testopt -ab
aflag = 1, bflag = 1, cvalue = (null)
```

Answer (score 2):

It behaves exactly as you would like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    int c;

    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "LU")) != -1) {
        switch (c) {
        case 'L':
            puts("'L' option");
            break;
        case 'U':
            // U catch
            puts("'U' option");
            break;
        default:
            puts("shouldn't get here");
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And test it:

```
precor@burrbar:~$ gcc -o test test.c
precor@burrbar:~$ ./test -LU
'L' option
'U' option
precor@burrbar:~$ ./test -L -U
'L' option
'U' option
```

[`getopt()` is a POSIX standard function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/functions/getopt.html) that follows the [POSIX "Utiltiy Syntax Guidelines"](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696799/basedefs/xbd_chap12.html#tag_12_02), which includes the following:

> Guideline 5:
>       Options without option-arguments should be accepted when grouped behind one '-' delimiter.